# How to match special characters such as ^ and \ without using indexOf()?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string if it is a valid "unit" in my program.

Valid units consists of:

`At least one letter, optional / or -, at least one more letter if you did the optional / or -`

Current attempt: `str.matches("[a-zA-z]*[-\\/]?[a-zA-z]*")`

Example:

```
Valid -> abc/abc
Valid -> abc
Invalid -> abc^abc
Invalid -> abc/abc
```

The invalid cases are showing as valid.

Comment: You are matching zero or one instances of `-` or `/` via the `?` metacharacter. In addition your regex is satisfied with zero letters before and zero letters after, so the empty string can be matched by this. Either anchor to the start and end with `^` and `$` or otherwise make your regex stricter

Comment: With updated question ([version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61090023/3)): `str.matches("[a-zA-z]+(?:[-/][a-zA-z]+)?")`

Comment: That's better, but it's failing when I try: abc\abc or abc^abc as the string. I think it has to do with those characters being used by regex as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.matches("(?i)[a-z]+([-/][a-z]+)?")
```

Notes:

- `(?i)` switchs on case insensitive matching, so you can code `[a-z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`, so it's easier to read
- `+` means "one or more"
- you do not ever need to escape `/`. It has no special regex meaning - it's just a plain old ordinary character
- `(...)?` means everythinig in the brackets is optional. That's how you make the "dash/slash plus letter(s)" expression optional as a whole

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Regex:

```
"[a-zA-z]+[-|\\/]{1}[a-zA-z]+"
```

Comment: 1) `{1}` is redundant. --- 2) Why are you escaping `/`? --- 3) Why are you matching `|`? --- 4) Why the two `+`? Match only needs to find one letter to match correctly.

Comment: + means one o more, according you question  [some letters] [ - or / ] [some letters] in case you do not want letters whether to right orleft you can use * since it means zero o more, 1) perhaps
 2) java requires it 
3) it means "or" 
4) each + belong to independent blocks

Comment: 2) *Java* doesn't require escaping `/`, since `/` is not a special character anywhere in a regex. *Other* programming languages, which use `/.../` around a regex literal, require escaping of `/`, but *Java* is not one of those languages. --- 3) `|` doesn't mean OR inside a `[ ]` character class, it is just a normal character being matched by the character class, which means that input `"abc|abc"` would be incorrectly accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to look for one and only one '-' or '/' character that is between at least one character on each side of it:

```
str.matches("[a-zA-z]{1,}[-\\/]{1}[a-zA-z]{1,}")
```

Comment: 1) `{1}` is redundant. *(Did you just copy from tino89's answer?)* --- 2) Why are you escaping `/`? --- 3) Why the two `{1,}` *(which is the same as `+`)*? Match only needs to find one letter to match correctly. --- 4) Your code would fail for input like `"x a-c y"`. Question just says *"match a string if it has a - or / between letters"*. Doesn't say anything about what else may be in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to updated question ([version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61090023/3)):

```
str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-/][a-zA-Z]+)?")
```

**Explanation**

> At least one letter

`[a-zA-Z]+`

> optional ... if you did the optional `/` or `-`

`(?:X)?` or `(X)?`

Both work, but the first is non-capturing, and since you don't need capturing, it is the more appropriate one to use.

> `/` or `-`

`[-/]`

> at least one more letter

`[a-zA-Z]+`

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("abc/abc", "abc", "abc^abc", "abc\\abc");
}
static void test(String... inputs) {
    for (String input : inputs)
        System.out.println((input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-/][a-zA-Z]+)?") ? "Valid" : "Invalid") + " -> " + input);
}
```

*Output*

```
Valid -> abc/abc
Valid -> abc
Invalid -> abc^abc
Invalid -> abc\abc
```

---

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61090023/how-to-match-special-characters-such-as-and-without-using-indexof/61090518#comment108077651_61090023):

> That's better, but it's failing when I try: `abc\abc` or `abc^abc` as the string. I think it has to do with those characters being used by regex as well.

Well, those are supposed to fail according to the listed rule.

If you meant that you want to modify the rule to also allow `\` and `^`, then you need to add them inside the `[ ]`.

But, you need to be aware of special characters inside `[ ]`:

- `-` is special, indicating a range, e.g. `a-z`, but not special if first or last. Escape with `\` if not first or last. Double the `\` when in a Java string literal to `\\`.
- `^` is special if first, meaning to reverse the list, e.g. `[^a-z]` means "*not* a lowercase letter`.
- `\` is always special, since it is the escape character, so you need to escape it as `\\`, and doubling them when in a Java string literal to `\\\\`.

Which means:

```
str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-/^\\\\][a-zA-Z]+)?")
```

*Test Output*

```
Valid -> abc/abc
Valid -> abc
Valid -> abc^abc
Valid -> abc\abc
Invalid -> abc#abc
```

Comment: This appears to fail for me when I try "abc^abc or abc\abc"